# After many repairs engine still vibrates (1995 Ford Probe, 4-cylinder, automatic)

Tags: engine, vibration

If memory serves me correctly, repairs / replacements include: all mounts (engine and transmission), torque converter, entire electrical system, harmonic balancer pulley, various sensors, checked for vacuum leaks, timing, frame was checked, and probably more that I don't remember. I've taken the car to various mechanics to no avail. The car has very good power, so I don't think it's a compression issue. I think I know what the usual suspects feel like (misfires, low compression, bad timing, etc.) and it's none of these. It feels like it's a mechanical issue inside the engine itself (or possibly the transmission). Vibrates at idle and all speeds, although it's not as pronounced at higher RPM's (but the vibration is still there). There is noise also... a loud low frequency "hum" (for lack of a better term) at lower RPM's which attenuates somewhat as the RPM's are increased. The "hum" is loud to the point that I sometimes wear ear protectors while driving. Would very much appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Year/make/model would go a long way to helping you!

Comment: Make? Age? Mileage? Size of engine?

Comment: Can you describe the vibration? Is the frequency related to engine speed, or vehicle speed?  Does it vibrate at idle? Is it an auto or manual?

Comment: It's a 1995 Ford Probe 4-cylinder.

Comment: Vibrates at idle and at all speeds, although at higher speeds it's attenuated a bit, but it's still there, but at a higher frequency of vibration.

Comment: Automatic transmission.

Comment: Is there a noise with the vibration?

Comment: Yes, there is noise... a loud low frequency "hum" (for lack of a better term) at lower RPM's which attenuates somewhat as the RPM's are increased.

Comment: Is the vibration the same under deceleration? If not, I'd suspect something combustion related (possibly a worn camshaft affecting an intake valve, since you seem to have checked everything else). If it is the same, the only thing I can think of would be to pull the oil pan and look for a piston skirt.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Yes, it vibrates during deceleration also. It's always vibrating. (I'll do a deceleration check just to make sure that what I'm saying is correct).

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions? Would appreciate any and all comments!